# How to debug WordPress correctly?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, debug, wp-debug, deprecation

I'm using a few plugins and UpThemes framework on my new website and if I turn on Wp Debug I can see that there are a few errors related to Deprecated functions (but website is working). What I would like to know is if there is a plugin, a software or a pray (lol) that I can use to know exactly where the deprecated code is so I'll be able to use the new one.

Which is the plugin/software that you use to debug your plugins, themes?

Comment: No plugin or software involved. Including `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php` (located in your wordpress installation's root folder) tells you the file and the line of every warning.

Comment: @Johannes Pille no, I'm sorry, it doesn't... it only says that inside my wp-include at line blablabla is written that has_cap is deprecated... ok thank you but where is has_cap in my code? :-)

Comment: Mkay. There is a misconception here. If the warning is about something in _/wp-icludes/xxx.php_, then the faulty code is in that file. It has nothing to do with your code. The core has its flaws as well...

Comment: Really so I have to upgrade my wp-include??? I didn't check it yet 'cause I tought that the problem was in my files :-)

Comment: Nope, you don't have to change nothing. 1. _Warnings_ and _Notices_ are not _Errors_. 2. If there are flaws in the core, they will most likely be sorted out in the next wp upgrade. One clarification: Does it report that something is wrong in said file or does it report that _according to_ said file something has been deprected? If the latter is the case, the flaw is not in said file. But again it need not be connected to your own code. Often plugins you have installed produce warnings as well. The older a plugin, the more likely it is to make use of deprecated stuff.

Comment: I found the problem :-) It was related to UpThemes Framework 2.0!
I had to change it to support roles and capabilities instead of numbers... I try to explain:
Admin WAS 10
Now:
Admin = upgrade_core
I simply changed this and everything worked without problems :-)
No more errors neither in Backend Nor in FrontEnd but it was a lucky find because wp-debug only told me that somewhere there was a permission error and it told me that on line X of wp-include/functions.php there was the echo of the deprecated error...

Comment: I'll contact UpThems on github and tell them to modify their Framework

Comment: Forked UpThemes Framework on GitHub, this is the working version: https://github.com/maisdesign/UpThemes-Framework/blob/42648c244d1d7e47694b8ad30638dbd096c05ead/admin/admin.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Log Deprecated Notices plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/log-deprecated-notices/). (Don't run it on a production site, as it is a direct-to-database log.)

What it'll do is convert those cryptic messages that are likely to reference has_cap() or some line in functions.php, to what's actually going on.

The [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin is also nice. It tracks notices of that pageload, using the conversion code from Log Deprecated Notices.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Theme Check](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/) in the past and found it very good. If I recall correctly, it checks against deprecated functions but most of all it suggests better functions to future-proof your theme, and alerts you when you're forgetting to implement features which WordPress' users have learnt to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do this is just using *grep* for the function name in it's theme/plugin folder. If your on windows you can use grepWin or agent ransack/powershell, etc.

Also install [debug-bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/), it's a lot nicer to look at.

Answer (score 0):

During theme development you can make debug mode on by changing Debug value to 'true' in root config.php

This will keep debug and show error during development.

Answer (score -2):

Zend's Z-Ray has a [theme profiler](http://serverdemo.zend.com/wordpress/). Also useful for seeing SQL queries.