# Blank screen at login/logout - tried everything!

Tags: fatal-error

I am working on some customized themes and when they are activated I cant log out, it goes blank. If I get rid of all cookies (being logged out) I cant log back in. The login.php shows, but when I've filled out the login form and hit the login button it's just a blank page showing.

As you probably figured I've tried everything I could come up with, that including googeling for days and trying all solutions I've found. There are no empty lines or spaces anywhere, I've disabled all plugins, I've even tried to rewrite one of the themes using twentyeleven as base. I'm out of ideas where to look.

My theme is not an ordinary blog theme but suppose to become a website. All other themes I've tried is working, including some free themes and twentyeleven. I can log in/out when they are enabled. The strangest thing is that everything worked just fine yesterday and today it doesn't, I thought rewriting it solved the problem, but no.

Any ideas where to go from here?

Hoping for answers before I go bald,
Bellisia

Comment: Since the problem is directly related to the theme it might help to provide more details along with any recent changes to the theme and any relevant functions.php code that could be causing the problem.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! :) I've tried to debug it through wp-config, nothing. I cant find anything in the log on my local version, and I cant find the log on the one that's up. Have tried to remove functions from functions.php, only some from twentyeleven left. Been through that file like 100 times, but I will try all of this again. More ideas are mostly welcome!

Comment: Now it seems to be working on the localhost (don't ask me why). But still not able to log in/out when having the theme activated on the "real" one.

Answer (score 1):

I think is an problem of php code, maybe in your functions.phg of the theme. Start debugging feature in WP and see the error messages.

add this to wp-config.php or change the constant in the file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE );
```

Also i think, read this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34037/how-to-debug-wordpress-correctly) and his answers, many solutions for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! :) I've tried to debug it through wp-config, nothing. I cant find anything in the log on my local version, and I cant find the log on the one that's up. Have tried to remove functions from functions.php, only some from twentyeleven left. Been through that file like 100 times, but I will try all of this again and look at the link. More ideas are mostly welcome!

Comment: Now it seems to be working on the localhost (don't ask me why). But still not able to log in/out when having the theme activated on the "real" one.

Comment: do you get an php error message? Do you have deactivate all caching tools an your local dev machine?

Comment: No php errors and I don't know actually, I will look that up :)

Comment: As far as I can see I don't have any caching tools activated, but since I'm pretty new at this I might be wrong. How does that change the "real" WordPress installation and theme?

Comment: Set only Standard-Theme Twenty Eleven and no plugins, works your Installation? After this activate only your theme, test ist. If you have also problems, check at first the functions.php; rename to .php.old; is not neccassary for the Theme; maybe you have an coding error.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I really appreciate it! I've recoded the theme one more time and I took a look at the sidebar this time and really dug into how it's suppose to look. I can't see any difference but something I did made it work. Hopefully things will continue working from now and no more blank pages. The most annoying thing is that I don't even know what I did different. But suddenly I can both change settings, log in/out and the blank screens are gone :) Thanks again!